# Local Npm module "grunt-angular-gettext" not found error when using angular-gettext

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, translation, angular-translate

i want to use angular-gettext to implement i18n on my app, i followed this http://lostechies.com/gabrielschenker/2014/02/11/angularjspart-12-multi-language-support/
i used this commands :

```
  npm install -g grunt-cli
  npm install grunt
  npm install grunt-angular-gettext
```

my Gruntfile.js :

```
 module.exports=function(grunt){
grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-angular-gettext');
//This task will parse all our source files and extract the texts we want to have translated – the ones that have an associated translate directive – and add them to a so called pot file.
grunt.initConfig({
    nggettext_extract:{ //we define the task name we want to configure or initialize
        pot:{
            files:{
                'po/template.pot':['../templates/*.html'] //we want the task to parse all html files in the current directory or any sub directory of it and output the result of the task into a file called template.pot
            }
        }
    },
    nggettext_compile:{
        all:{
            files:{
            'translations.js':['po/*.po'] //we want this task to load all po files in the subfolder po of the current directory and compile them into a resulting file translations.js located in the current directory.
            }
        }
        }
});

  }
```

when i use this command grunt nggettext_extract to extract tranlation i have this error :

```
  >> Local Npm module "grunt-angular-gettext" not found. Is it installed?
   Warning: Task "nggettext_extract" not found. Use --force to continue.

   Aborted due to warnings.
```

i don't know why? the package grunt-angular-gettext exists in node modules
can you help me to deal with this?

Answer (score 5):

Try to run in your project folder:

```
npm install grunt-angular-gettext --save-dev
```

I had a similar issue and running the above command did the trick for me

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will help you or not, but I was getting the same error, and after some time looking into it, I realized that my nggettext_extract entry in grunt.initConfig was incorrect, I had it at the wrong level (I accidentally put it inside shell), I see that's not your problem, but it might still be something in the Gruntfile.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to first make sure that you have a package.json file in the directory.

run: 
 npm init
then
 npm install grunt
 npm install grunt-angular-gettext

This will install the actual module. 
More on this topic can be found: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/issues/232